# datatable sort method not working!

Tags: c#

here is my datatable:

```
DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
dttemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("position", typeof(string)));
dttemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("specimen", typeof(string)));
```

i am sorting like this and then importing every row into a different datatable:

```
view = dttemp.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "position";

foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
   dt_final.ImportRow(row);
```

here are the two rows that it is supposed to sort however as you can see it is not sorting

```
D01 PAINCAL4
F01 PAINQC2
A01 PAINCAL1
C01 PAINCAL3
E01 PAINQC1
G01 PAINQC3
H01 PAINQC4
```

it is supposed to sort on the first column

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach (DataRowView row in dttemp.DefaultView) 
        dt_final.ImportRow(row.Row);
```

Comment: IMPORTROW can only be used on DATAROW

Comment: Changed the example to pass a DataRow to the ImportRow method.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing the rows of the dataTable, the datatable itself is not sorted, you will want to iterate through the DataRowView

**EDIT:**

```
 foreach (DataRowView drv in dv) // replace your vars
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < dv.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
               Console.WriteLine(drv[i]);
         }
```